# Android Google Speech Recognizer very slow after Google update

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech

I am developing an app that makes use of google's offline and online voice recognition for Android. Ever since the June 30th update to the Google app, after I speak for my app,the recognition takes 4 seconds as opposed to .5 seconds. This applies also to both online and offline voice recognition in my app. This was tested on multiple devices and after updating the google app, the speed decreased in speech recognition for my app dramatically.

Is this just temporary from Google, or is there something I can do to increase the speech of the voice recognition result time?